# Copying and pasting between ChromeOS and Linux X11 apps

Tags: linux, xorg, google-chrome-os

Running Linux on ChromeOS in developer mode, it is simple to run xterm. I simply install it with apt and then execute it, and the window seamlessly opens on the ChromeOS desktop. What is not simple is pasting into that xterm.

Any ideas? At the moment, nothing appears to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure why. When I copy to the chromeos clipboard with Ctrl-C, say, from Chrome, I cannot paste into the xterm.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through `man xterm` in the section titled *Default Key Bindings* you can see what input events call the function `insert-selection()` which corresponds to "paste":

```
 Shift <KeyPress> Insert:insert-selection(SELECT, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\
 ~Ctrl ~Meta <Btn2Up>:insert-selection(SELECT, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\
```

So there are 2 actions, keypress <kbd>Insert</kbd> with Shift, and mouse button 2 press (without Control nor Meta). There isn't an insert key on Chromebooks, and I don't get a paste action from any button clicks on the mousepad either.

What you can do is add your own overriding key binding. For example, to make <kbd>Ctrl Shift V</kbd> do a paste, run `xterm` from a shell script like this:

```
xterm -xrm '*VT100*translations:      #override \n\
            Ctrl Shift <Key>V:  insert-selection(PRIMARY,CLIPBOARD) \n\
           '
```

(The backslash is the last character on the line).
See the same man page for *Custom Key Bindings*.

Comment: So, that is causing a paste, but it is pasting from the X11 clipboard and not the ChromeOS clipboard. I'm wondering if there is a custom clipboard application to run in X11 to bridge the two.

Comment: The `insert-selection()` function can take a series of names of properties to test in the given order. Typically, the PRIMARY selection is the one most used to pass copied items, but there is also SECONDARY, SELECT, CLIPBOARD and CUT_BUFFER0 to 7. I don't know which ChromeOS uses, but PRIMARY worked for me in a quick test. The problem can also be that if using Wayland rather than pure X11, it may change things too. I don't have any further insight to offer, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

So I did find a solution but I don't really understand why. I installed stterm from suckless.org, and through random experimentation I found that Ctrl-Shift-V will paste into it from the chromebook clipboard.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).